# Identify shopify consent cookie name in chrome developer

Tags: shopify, google-tag-manager, privacy, shopify-api, cookieconsent

just a quick question: I try to find the name of the shopify consent cookie used by shopify conent API for GTM consent mode config.

What I also found out is that even when I remove all cookies, all 3rd party cookies are still loaded.

Site concerned: https://casualmode.fr

Thx community :)

Comment: If you're trying to avoid the cookies, you can use an extension like https://github.com/Cookie-AutoDelete/Cookie-AutoDelete

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is called "_tracking_consent", you can find it in the browser console.
To read it, you have to decode its value first parse it (since its a JSON).
After doing so, you can read its propertys according to your demand.

```
function readShopifyConsentCookie() {
  //use built in GTM variable to read cookie value https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWF14.png
  var consentCookie = {{_tracking_consent}};
  //returns the object - if you need a certain key-value pair out of the object, feel free to add more lines of code :D
  return JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(consentCookie)); 
}
```